# JQuery modal form DIV that does a window.location.href with querystring values from the form

Tags: jquery, forms, modal-dialog

I'd like to use a jQuery Modal Dialog of some kind to present 4 or 5 options on a form to a user. When the user clicks Save, the dialogue would validate and then window.location.href somewhere else using values from the form in the arguments.

I can't find a good example of doing this; almost every sample is Ajax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a jQuery UI Dialog, you have to define the HTML for it on the page and then call `dialog()` to display it. This isn't too practical when you need to change the options to display at runtime.

You could use a plugin I wrote to simplify this kind of task. You can create dialogs on demand wiht it. The plugin assumes that you already have the proper JS and a jQuery UI Theme installed. Here's the plugin: http://mosttw.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/dialogwrapper-simplified-use-of-jquery-ui-dialogs/  and here's an example:

```
$.showDialog("Title", "Choose your option:<br/> <input type='radio' value='1'/> Option 1<p></p>... etc.", {
    buttons: {
        'Ok': function() {
            // Do your validation here

            // And then close the dialog
            $.hideDialog();
        }
    }
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/BquUe/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using [facebox plugin](http://defunkt.github.com/facebox/)